# PHP Generated SVG as background image

Tags: php, css, svg

I want to dynamically change the colour of an SVG depending what background colour has been chosen. This is working, but it won't work as a background image as the filename is .php

Here is my PHP code which makes my image, I haven't included all the paths:

```
<?php 
header('Content-type: image/svg+xml');

function adjustBridgtness($rgb, $steps) {
    //Only allow RGB value to be sent
    if (count($rgb) == 3) {
        //Negative darker, positive brighter
        $steps = max(-255, min(255, $steps));

        //New color
        $new_color = array();

        foreach($rgb as $color) {
            //$color = hexdec($color); 
            $color = max(0,min(255,$color + $steps));
            $new_color[] = $color;
        }

        return $new_color;
    }
}
//$colors[0] = array(67,189,151); //Row 1

$colors[0] = adjustBridgtness(array(67,189,151),0); //Row 1
$colors[1] = array(81,193,159); //Row 2
$colors[2] = array(95,199,165); //Row 3
$colors[3] = array(107,203,173); //Row 4
$colors[4] = array(127,211,185); //Row 5
$colors[5] = array(81,193,159); //Diagonal Lines
$colors[6] = array(127,211,185); //Verticle Line

?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    width="796px" height="404px" viewBox="0 0 796 404">
    <path fillRule="evenodd" d="M 349.5 153.12C 349.5 153.12 396.88 200.5 396.88 200.5 396.88 200.5 349.5 247.88 349.5 247.88 349.5 247.88 302.12 200.5 302.12 200.5 302.12 200.5 349.5 153.12 349.5 153.12Z" fill="rgb(<?=$colors[0][0]?>,<?=$colors[0][1]?>,<?=$colors[0][2]?>)"/>
    <path fillRule="evenodd" d="M 251.5 153.12C 251.5 153.12 298.88 200.5 298.88 200.5 298.88 200.5 251.5 247.88 251.5 247.88 251.5 247.88 204.12 200.5 204.12 200.5 204.12 200.5 251.5 153.12 251.5 153.12Z" fill="rgb(<?=$colors[0][0]?>,<?=$colors[0][1]?>,<?=$colors[0][2]?>)"/>
</svg>
```

Im simply putting it in the background-image property like so:

```
background-image:url(images/image.php);
```

This isn't working though as its not displaying, what have I done wrong?

**P.S. Only the administrator of the website can change the background colour, would it be better to generate the SVG and overwrite an existing file such as `background.svg` when the colour is changed instead of generating the colours each time the page is loaded?**

Comment: have you tried closing your svg tag after the paths?

Comment: It is closed, I just didn't paste all of the bottom code, I will add it now so everyone knows its closed

Comment: does ist show up if you just browse to images/image.php?

Comment: Yeah, it works if I browse to it

Comment: is the url publicly accessible?

Comment: http://karl.uphero.com/images/background_banner1.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mmh, it works here...(at least for me)

```html
<div style="width:400px;height:400px;background-image:url(http://karl.uphero.com/images/background_banner1.php)"></div>
```

Comment: Hmm, I have linked it in a style sheet and not inline incase that makes a difference?

Comment: Hmm, it seems to be working actually, but it's not updating :S 
http://karl.uphero.com/ See it there, the top colours of the squares are different then when you load it here:
http://karl.uphero.com/images/background_banner1.php

Comment: Hmm, strange, seems to be working now. I think it was caching... but now it reloads when I refresh the page.